# Jackson Serialize List Entities (add field to root list)

Tags: java, json, jpa, jackson, wildfly

this my entity

```
@Entity
public class Product extends AbstractBaseEntity {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Type(type = "objectid")
   private String id;
   private String title;
```

my resources

```
@Path(value = ApiConstant.Urls.PRODUCTS)
public class ProductResource {

   @Inject
   private ProductService productService;

   @GET
   @Path(value = ApiConstant.Urls.PRODUCTS)
   @Produces(value = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   public List getProducts(){
      return productService.findAll();
   }
```

my json response

```
[ {
  "id" : "596b6a02f70a0878590bcf08",
  "title" : "test1",
  "description" : "description test 1"
}, {
  "id" : "596b6b00f70a087b72d377eb",
  "title" : "test1",
  "description" : "description test 1"
}, {
  "id" : "596b6b75f70a087d40f580d5",
  "title" : "test1",
  "description" : "description test 1"
} ]
```

I want to create a count field that counts the items in the list
like this and add the list to the results field

```
{
    "count": 3,
    "results":  [ 
     {
      "id" : "596b6a02f70a0878590bcf08",
      "title" : "test1",
      "description" : "description test 1"
    }, {
      "id" : "596b6b00f70a087b72d377eb",
      "title" : "test1",
      "description" : "description test 1"
    }, {
      "id" : "596b6b75f70a087d40f580d5",
      "title" : "test1",
      "description" : "description test 1"
    } ], 
}
```

I want to serialize the Product List returned by jpa persistence

Comment: You could create a new class `ProductsWrapper` with `count` and `results` and then create an instance of this in the `getProducts` method and return it instead of the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following class to include a count along with a list of `Product` entities:

```
public class ResultList {
    private int count;
    @JsonProperty("results") private List<Product> products;

    public List<Product> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }

    public void setProducts(List<Product> products) {
        this.products = Objects.requireNonNull(products, "products");
        this.count = products.size();
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Class with generics type

```
public class ResultList<T> {

    private int count;
    @JsonProperty("results")
    private List<T> items;

    public List<T> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(List<T> items) {
        this.items = Objects.requireNonNull(items, "items");
        this.count = items.size();
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }
}
```

ProductResource

```
@GET
@Path(value = ApiConstant.Urls.PRODUCTS)
@Produces(value = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public ResultList getProducts(){
    List products = productService.findAll();
    ResultList result = new ResultList<Product>();
    result.setItems(products);
    return result;

}
```

Thanks @ck1